# Octave: Values inside a matrix that are close

Tags: vector, octave

I have a vector that is being filled with random numbers within this range [0,1]. I want to somehow accept only the vectors, in which an element inside of it has a maximum deviation of 0,02 from its previous one and its next one.
For example I have the below vector [3,1]. This is acceptable, because the deviation of the 2nd element, between the first and the third element is not bigger than 0,02. Vector is not always consisted of 3 rows, it could be more.

```
**Vector**

0.32957

0.33097

0.33946
```

This is what i thought:

```
n=4
P=rand(1,n);

sort(P,"ascend");

for L=2:n
    while P(L-1)-P(L)>0.02
      P=rand(1,n);

    endwhile
endfor
```

Comment: @CrisLuengo You are right, edited the post.

Comment: Wait, so you just want that the difference between maximum and minimum values of the vector is less than 0.02?

Comment: Since the vector is sorted(ascending), the first element is always the smallest. So I want the next one, being bigger by maximum 0.02. For example, [0.45,0.47,0.48,0.50] is acceptable for n=4. Whereas, this one is not acceptable [0.33,0.46,0.47,0.49]. Every element has to be close by 0.02 to its next and previous element.

Comment: why do you not generate the first random value and than all the others as random increment of 0.02 from previous one ?

Comment: Please note the implication of restricting the sequence to be in the range `[0,1]` is that its starting value and its length are also limited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vectorize this!

```
isvalid=~any(diff(sort(a))>0.02);
```

`sort(a)` : if its not sorted, sort

`diff()`  : take the difference between adjacent elements

`___ >0.02`: Check if any of those differences is bigger than what you accept

`~any()`: if any is bigger, then return zero, "not valid".

---

From your code, it seems that there may be more to the question than what you ask, you seem to have the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You want to create a random vector that has the properties that you describe. You seem to be using uniform random numbers, so let me propose a way to generate your vector where your conditions are always true.

```
a(1)=rand(1); %or any other way to generate a first value.
length=100;   %desired length.
a(2:length)=rand(length-1,1)*0.02; %generate random numbers never bigger than 0.02
a=cumsum(a); %cumulative sum
```

This ensures the vector is increasing in value, and never increasing more than 0.02

Comment: Your first command helped solved it. I am aware of what you suggested regarding 0.02 increase after the Random Value, but this is not the actual problem itself. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: @Unknown225 try to avoid falling in the XY problem trap! Glad it helped.